# Loop doesn't stop, and doesn't answer to a module correctly

Tags: java, loops, module, break

So, I have my code which, basically when taking a certain number it will certify if the module the result is equal to 0, and if it is so, it will divide it self by the prime number, otherwise it will go to the next prime number, and try to get if the module is equal to 0... if it fails all of the numbers until 11, it will print it self and then, it will break the loop... the problem is, it either doesn't break, or even if the result is 0 it doesn't divide it self, this is my code...

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Problem3 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int pfactor = 2;
    double num = 13195;
    double dfactor;
    while (true) {
        dfactor = pfactor;
        if (num % dfactor == 0.0) {
            num = num / dfactor;
        }
        else {
            switch (pfactor) {
            case 2:
                pfactor = 3;
            case 3:
                pfactor = 5;
            case 5:
                pfactor = 7;
            case 7:
                pfactor = 11;
            case 11:
                out.println(num);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Your switch statement is incorrect. You are missing a 'brake' at the end of each case; in your current code both 2, 3, 4, 7 and 11 ends up printing the number and for 2, 3, 5, 7 pfactor will be 11. I assume the break in the 'case 11' is meant to break the loop, while in reality it breaks the switch label. To break the loop from inside a switch, you must create a custom label for it:

```
loop: while(true){
...}
```

and then call `break loop;` from the switch.

If you want to avoid the breaks in the switch cases, you can use the arrow operator instead:

```
switch(pfactor){
  case 2 ->pfactor=3;
  case 3 ->pfactor=5;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking out of the `switch`, and not from `while` loop. You could use a flag to exit while loop or `System.exit(0);` to exit program.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` inside your case 11 refers to the scope of the switch statement and will break out of it, and not your loop. Additionally, you're missing `break` statements after every other case, meaning if you reach case 2 you will also go through case 3, 5, 7, and 11, ultimately ending up with `pfactor = 11;`. This means, if 13195 % 2 and 13195 % 11 are both not 0, you end up in an infinite loop.

First you should add `break` statements after every case, and in case 11 set for example a boolean flag, which if it is true, breaks out of the loop.

```java
boolean breakOut = false;
while (true) {
    dfactor = pfactor;
    if (num % dfactor == 0.0) {
        num = num / dfactor;
    }
    else {
        switch (pfactor) {
        case 2:
            pfactor = 3;
            break;
        case 3:
            pfactor = 5;
            break;
        case 5:
            pfactor = 7;
            break;
        case 7:
            pfactor = 11;
            break;
        case 11:
            out.println(num);
            breakOut = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (breakOut) {
      break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the problems that others already pointed out. You are complicating a lot by using switch, use an array instead:

```
public class Problem3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double num = 13195;
        int [] prime_numbers = new int []{2, 3, 5, 7, 11};
        for(int p : prime_numbers){
            while(num % p == 0){
                num = num / p;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

What happen if you want to add 100 new prime numbers? are you gone add 100 switch branches?

Put the prime numbers on an array, iterator over them, and do the necessary calculations.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do it like that :

```
boolean continueLoop = true;
while(continueLoop){
...
}
```

when you want to exit loop, you can simply say

```
continueLoop=false;
```